# Retrieve all the pages within a space with ScriptRunner

Tags: confluence, confluent-schema-registry, confluence-rest-api, scriptrunner-for-jira, confluence-macros

I am writing code in the script console to list the pages in a specific space called IWIKI. I am using the following code:

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Page

import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.PageManager

import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space

import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager

import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator

import com.atlassian.confluence.api.service.content.SpaceService

import com.atlassian.confluence.api.model.content.Space

import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space

import com.atlassian.confluence.api.service.content.SpaceService

import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl

def spaceManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SpaceManager)

def pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager)

 

String spaceKey = "IWIKI"

SpaceService spaceService = ScriptRunnerImpl.getPluginComponent(SpaceService)

// here's the tricky part, just go with it

Space space = spaceService.find().withKeys(spaceKey).fetch()

List<Page> pages = pageManager.getPages(space, true)
```

I am getting the following error:

[image]

Anyone knows what the problem is? I think spaceService.find().withKeys(spaceKey).fetch() is returning an object of type com.atlassian.confluence.api.model.content.Space and the next line pageManager.getPage(space, true) is expecting a space parameter of type com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.links.OutgoingLink
import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Page
import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.PageManager
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor
import com.atlassian.sal.api.user.UserKey

SpaceManager spaceManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SpaceManager)
PageManager pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager)
UserAccessor userAccessor = ComponentLocator.getComponent(UserAccessor)

Space space = spaceManager.getSpace("IWIKI")


for (Page page : pageManager.getPages(space, true)) {
    if(page.getCreator()==null){
            log.warn(page.toString()+",null")
    }
    else{
            String userID=page.getCreator().getName()
            String fullName =userAccessor.getUserByKey(page.getCreator().getKey()).getFullName()
            log.warn(page.toString()+","+userID+","+fullName+","+page.getLastModificationDate())

    }

   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatted code:

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Page
import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.PageManager
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
import com.atlassian.confluence.user.UserAccessor
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager

Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("my.logger")

SpaceManager spaceManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SpaceManager)
PageManager pageManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(PageManager)
UserAccessor userAccessor = ComponentLocator.getComponent(UserAccessor)
Space space = spaceManager.getSpace("IWIKI")

for (Page page : pageManager.getPages(space, true)) {
   if (page.getCreator() == null) {
      logger.warn("${page.toString()} is null")
   } else {
      String userID = page.getCreator().getName()
      String fullName = userAccessor.getUserByKey(page.getCreator().getKey()).getFullName()
      logger.warn("${page.toString()}, ${userID}, ${fullName}, ${page.getLastModificationDate()}")
   }
}
```